# plugin settings in intelj idea

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, settings

does anyone know how to go to the plugin settings in intelj Idea? I'll attach a screenshot to make it clear what I mean. Thank you everyone in advance and have a nice day

There is nothing like that in the installed plugins menu

[сamel case plugin descrition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8zzn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All IDE settings are presented in the `File | Settings` or `<IDE_name> | Settings` window.
Some plugins create a separate category on the left, for example, the Rainbow Brackets plugin, other place their settings under existing categories. If you have no idea to which exact category the plugin's settings belong, you can use search field on the top left:

[image: settings-search]